# Error while trying to insert rsa key (tuple) into sql database

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlite, rsa

I am learning `sqlite3` and I tried inserting an `rsa` key into one of my columns that I made but I get this error:

```
sqlite3.InterfaceError: Error binding parameter 2 - probably unsupported type.
```

Here's my code:

```
import sqlite3, rsa

db = sqlite3.connect('database.db')
db.execute('drop table if exists user')
db.execute('create table user (username text, password text, pubKey tuple, 
privKey tuple)')

username = input("Input Username: ")
password = input("Input Password: ")
confirm = input("Confirm Password: ")
(pubKey, privKey) = rsa.newkeys(512)

if password == confirm:
    db.execute('insert into user (username, password, pubKey, privKey) values (?, ?, ?, ?)', (username, password, pubKey, privKey))
    db.commit()
else:
    quit()
```

I am using rsa.newkeys to generate the keys and they generate as tuples. For example the tuple will be something along the lines of:

PublicKey(7993225774562669856453147392958346571937702133919317490212017912216372852796080413531673713173968180340315460310318908937895213458133041784535151317298739, 65537)

I looked at the documentation for rsa and rsa.newkeys() dpes return a tuple but I get the error saying it is the wrong data type.

Comment: What is the `type` of those arguments? They are most likely class instances that aren't subclasses of either str or int. You need to serialize the keys for storage.

Comment: You don't link the lib that you are using for RSA, but it probably is [`rsa.newkeys()`](https://stuvel.eu/python-rsa-doc/reference.html#rsa.newkeys). The types are [`rsa.PublicKey`](https://stuvel.eu/python-rsa-doc/reference.html#rsa.PublicKey) and [`rsa.PrivateKey`](https://stuvel.eu/python-rsa-doc/reference.html#rsa.PrivateKey). Dive into these docs to get more info on how to use them for your case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

pubKey and privKey are instances of the classes (rsa.key.PublicKey and rsa.key.PrivateKey)

From the instance you could take both vallues as int:

`pubKey.n` - from your example it's 7993225774562669856453147392958346571937702133919317490212017912216372852796080413531673713173968180340315460310318908937895213458133041784535151317298739

`pubKey.e` - it's 65537

If you need only the keys, save int to the db:

```
db.execute('create table user (username text, password text, pubKey int, privKey int)')
...
db.execute('insert into user (username, password, pubKey, privKey) values (?, ?, ?, ?)', (username, password, pubKey.n, privKey.n))
```

If you need a whole string, convert to str and save as text:

```
db.execute('create table user (username text, password text, pubKey text, privKey text)')
...
db.execute('insert into user (username, password, pubKey, privKey) values (?, ?, ?, ?)', (username, password, str(pubKey), str(privKey)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at your RSA key - it's probably hex (i.e. there are numbers AND letters) so int will not work. Int is for numbers only.

I'd suggest either using text or blob for the type.

Comment: Blobs and texts dont work. I discovered that the data type of the pubkey and privkey are tuples. But when I change the column type to tuple it still doesnt work. I edited my post with more info